# How to make enter key work on EditTextPreference dialog

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I gave `android:singleLine="true"` option on `EditTextPreference`, and when the edit box in the dialog has the focus, the software keyboard shows "Done" button in place of Enter key. However if I press the done button, only the software keyboard closes, and I still have to click Done button on the dialog.

Is there anyway to make enter key and ime action key on the software keyboard to close the dialog and apply the new value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I set the IME Option to IME_ACTION_DONE

```
mEditTextPreference.getEditText().setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

and then using following code to save value and close dialog.

```
mEditTextPreference.getEditText().setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //mEditTextPreference.setText(mEditTextPreference.getEditText().getText().toString());

            //better solution
            mEditTextPreference.onClick(mEditTextPreference.getDialog(), Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            mEditTextPreference.getDialog().dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to trick it to think the positive button was clicked by calling `editPref.onClick(editPref.getDialog(), DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);` before calling `dismiss()`. It's a hackish way, but this way I can reuse the same logic.

Comment: Your solution is better then mine, I merged it into post. thanks :D

Comment: Even better is to set the ime in the xml layout in your edit text like this: `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`.

Comment: There is no "getDialog" , at least not on android-x

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `using android:inputType="textCapSentences"` (textCapSentences is one of many options) in the XML for the edit text. I had a similar problem and that was able to solve it also gave me control of what keyboard I could show.

For instance if I had a number only field I could use `android:inputType="number"` which would show the number pad vs the qwerty keyboard first, there are many different options

Comment: Sorry I saw this late, but I don't care about keyboard type. I just want the enter key to close the dialog and apply the changed value. I guess I have to create my own dialog for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `DialogPreference` with `EditText` should normally always close itself when user presses <kbd>Done</kbd> button and soft keyboard closes. To make this behavior by default it's easy to implement a customized `EditTextPreferenceCustomized` and then use it everywhere instead of standard `EditTextPreference`.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class EditTextPreferenceCustomized extends EditTextPreference
{
    public EditTextPreferenceCustomized(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextPreferenceCustomized(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextPreferenceCustomized(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAddEditTextToDialogView(View dialogView, EditText editText)
    {
        super.onAddEditTextToDialogView(dialogView, editText);

        // editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE); - uncomment if it's not specified in preferences.xml

        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
              if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
              {
                onClick(getDialog(), Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code is partially based on the helpful solution from @LZN, but this will eliminate the need for setting action listener for every preference in java code. Just replace in preferences.xml all instances of `EditTextPreference` to `com.yourpackage.EditTextPreferenceCustomized`.

Comment: Sadly onAddEditTextToDialogView is now gone on android-x

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the AlertDialog with EditText in code ...:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
// (do other stuff here with dialog)
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE); // show "Done" on keyboard
// (do other stuff here with et)
AlertDialog createDialog = dialog.create();
createDialog.show();
```

... you can "press" the positive button like this:

```
et.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) { 
        createDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```